# Angular *ngFor accessing specific value of an array

Tags: angular, input

i am new to Angular.  The task i have to do is to create a reusable component from PrimeNG carousel. In the scenario user will have to enter from what array and what fields should be used to display data in the carousel.Then those parameters will be bind to the reusable component.

Is there any way to say in HTML something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of  someArray">
    <ul>
        <li>{{x.[specificField]}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then in TS file get specificField parameter from another's component array?
For example get names from array:

```
@Input()
someArray:Array<anotherArray>

@Input()
specificField:anotherArray.name
```

Thank you

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you add some more details with an example data set and describe what should be the expected behavior?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: It's done by specifying the name of the field.  e.g. x.firstname, x.lastname etc.

Comment: Well... you can but the access should be without the dot, x[ index ] here the index to access the inner array

Comment: Thank you Joel!!!! That is what i was looking for!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your data set. So just adding one sample data set for your reference.

Component:

```
let someArray= [{'name':'abc'}, {'name':'bcd'}, {'name3':'cde'}];
let field = 'name';
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of someArray">
  {{data[field]}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is read the property by name. That is very much possible.

I just assumed, a collection of some interface and here is a sample.

Here is the hello-component.ts

```js
  @Input()
  someArray:Array<Employee>

  @Input()
  specificField:string[];
```

Here is the template to render.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of someArray">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let name of specificField">{{name}} : {{item[name]}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>`
```

Example `interface`,

```js
export interface Employee {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Here is some sample input for your `hello-component`

```js
  someArray = [
    {name: 'Person 1', age: 23},
    {name: 'Person 2', age: 33},
    {name: 'Person 3', age: 47},
    {name: 'Person 4', age: 43},
    {name: 'Person 5', age: 45},
  ] as Array<Employee>;

  specificField = ['name', 'age'];
```

Output:

[image: Output of the code]

Here is the stackblittz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qqf8sn?file=src/app/hello.component.ts